# how and/or where is email address form data stored?

Tags: internet-explorer-8

When one brings up a web page that contains fields to be populated by an email address, I typically get a long drop down list of addresses that I have used in the past.

where is this stored in the registry? One location, multiple locations?

Is it directly accessible?

I want to delete some ...not all...of them.

Comment: Wouldn't this belong on superuser, not SO?

Answer (score 0):

These are not stored in the windows registry.  They are maintained by the particular browser you're using.  Therefore, how to access/delete them will depend on which browser you're using.  As an example, in some browsers, you can simply move down to the one you want to delete, and hit the delete key.

Comment: Using IE 8. They must be "stored" someplace. Is in the cookies folder?

Comment: @treasur2 they have a special "database" on disk they use.